# How to get rough age of a timestamp/datetime object?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

In PHP, if I have a `datetime` object or `timestamp` as properties of an object, how can I get a rough age for the record in PHP.

So that instead of a formated date string it says something like
`"about 1 hour ago", "3 days ago", "1 year ago"` etc.
A bit like redmine has for task comments, for example.

What is this process called?
I tried searching for age and `datetime` and keep finding code to get someone's age of birth, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's usually referred to as a 'fuzzy date'

Answer (score 1):

if you have 2 objects. You need to convert first object to timestamp and second object is time();

> [time()](http://php.net/time) - Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Then you substract time() with date you want and you get difference in seconds. To make minutes from seconds you need divide it  by `60`, to make hours you need to divide it by `60 * 60 = 3600` etc.

```
$secondsAgo = time() - $timeStamp;
$minutesAgo= (time() - $timeStamp) / 60; 
$hoursAgo= (time() - $timeStamp) / 60*60;
$daysAgo= (time() - $timeStamp) / 60*60*24;
```

To change string to timestamp you can use [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

The other solution is to use diff() on DateTime object.

```
 $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
 $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
 $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
 echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

This returns [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object which has a lot of properties that are public

- **y** Number of years.
- **m** Number of months.
- **d** Number of days.
- **h** Number of hours.
- **i** Number of minutes.
- **s** Number of seconds.